# Registering component multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I need to instantiate a concrete class based on data in the HttpRequestMessage. I'm using the following code to configure my Web API service:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterHttpRequestMessage(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(WebApiApplication).Assembly);

// ... snip ....
container.Register(x =>
{
  if (x.IsRegistered<HttpRequestMessage>())
  {
    var httpRequestMethod = x.Resolve<HttpRequestMessage>();

    var tokenHelper = x.Resolve<ITokenHelper>();
    var token = tokenHelper.GetToken(httpRequestMethod);

    var connectionContext = x.Resolve<ISqlServerConnectionContext>();
    connectionContext.Token = token;

    return token ?? new NullMinimalSecurityToken();
  }

  return new NullMinimalSecurityToken();
});
// ... snip ...

var container = builder.Build();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

return container;
```

Unfortunately, the delegate is called multiple times, with the last one not having a registered HttpRequestMessage, meaning I get back a NullMinimalSecurityToken, which causes my security attribute to reject the request (as it should). However, when I'm stepping through, I can see that IMinimalSecurityToken is already registered (i.e. `x.IsRegistered<IminimalSecurityToken()` returns true). If I try to return the resolved IMinimalSecurityToken if it's already registered, I get a circular reference error.

In addition, attempting to use `InstancePerApiRequest` while registering results in a "No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested" error.

I'm not entirely clear on why this delegate gets called multiple times, nor why in one of the calls it doesn't have an HttpRequestMethod.

What am I doing wrong that is causing multiple executions of the delegate (assuming that is in fact a problem), and how do I fix this so that I can properly inject a valid IMinimalSecurityToken into my SecurityAttribute (via property injection, but that part is working, it's just that what gets injected isn't valid).

Comment: Probably not relevant, but just in case, I'm converting this project from Ninject to Autofac, and I started from the Ninject configuration code and modified that to get to this point.

Answer (score 0):

So this problem turned out to be caused by trying to "convert" the Ninject code over to Autofac.

I was able to use Autofac's capabilities to inject Web API filters to wire up the security attribute, which allowed me to inject the required IMinimalSecurityToken in the constructor, rather than the rather hacky way I had to work around Ninject's limitations in that area:

```
container.RegisterType<SecurityTokenAuthorization>().As<IAutofacAuthorizationFilter>().InstancePerApiRequest();
container.RegisterType<SecurityTokenAuthorization>().AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterFor<DocumentController>().InstancePerApiRequest();
```

I've got other issues now, but they are sufficiently different that they'll need a new question assuming I'm not able to solve them.